# How to use same username account for multiple users?

Tags: customization, username

I have an ecommerce where I need to use same username for differents customers.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're using WordPress-native usernames, you can't. WP doesn't allow duplicate usernames because it wouldn't know which account to log into.

Comment: You could instead associate orders to certain user groups, instead of individual users - it would depend on what ecommerce solution you're using, and would require some custom code.

Comment: Thansk a lot for your answer! I thought there was a chance for wordpress to know wich account to log into because email adress and first name is different on each account.